# How to control colorbar position when using subplots in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to use Matplotlib to plot a time series along with its spectrogram and its associated colorbar.

Below is a MCVE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as scignal
import random

array=np.random.random(10000)
t,f,Sxx=scignal.spectrogram(array,fs=100)

plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(array)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.pcolormesh(Sxx)
plt.colorbar()
```

This code yields the following figure:

[image]

However, I would like both subplots to have the same size:

[image]

I thought of changing the orientation of the colorbar using `plt.colorbar(orientation='horizontal')` but I am not satisfied with the result as the subplots end up not having the same height.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is that `plt.colorbar` creates a *new* `Axes` object, which "steals" space from the lower `Axes` (this is the reason making a horizontal colourbar also affects the two original plots).

There are a few ways to work around this; one is to create a `Figure` with four `Axes`, allocate most of the space to the left ones, and just make one invisible:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal as scignal
import random

array = np.random.random(10000)
t, f, Sxx = scignal.spectrogram(array,fs=100)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(5, 6), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [19, 1]})
(ax1, blank), (ax2, ax_cb) = axes
blank.set_visible(False)
ax1.plot(array)
m = ax2.pcolormesh(Sxx)
fig.colorbar(m, cax=ax_cb)
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for your quick reply, gmds! Your workaround is exactly what I was looking for! Creating a 2 by 2 grid works for me.